# Android Studio Java Does not connect to CharGPT API but in IntelliJ IDEA the code works fine

Tags: java, android, android-studio, openai-api, chatgpt-api

My Java code when run in  IntelliJ IDEA connects to OpenAI API and returns the response easily without any problem. However, when I run exactly the same code in the Android Studio, it only runs until the line and the the app breaks and exit from running.

```
OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
```

Here is the entire code which is simple:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class ChatGPTAPIExample {

    public static String chatGPT(String prompt) {
        String url = "https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions";
        String apiKey "";
        String model = "gpt-3.5-turbo";

        try {
            URL obj = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + apiKey);
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

            // The request body
            String body = "{\"model\": \"" + model + "\", \"messages\": [{\"role\": \"user\", \"content\": \"" + prompt + "\"}]}";
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
            writer.write(body);
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();

            // Response from ChatGPT
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            String line;

            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(line);
            }
            br.close();

            // calls the method to extract the message.
            return extractMessageFromJSONResponse(response.toString());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public static String extractMessageFromJSONResponse(String response) {
        int start = response.indexOf("content") + 11;

        int end = response.indexOf("\"", start);

        return response.substring(start, end);

    }
}
```

I am wondering why in Android Studio it is not working. Is there any configuration I should set? All I do is simply calling the function on a button click:

```
botton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                String response= ChatGPTAPIExample.chatGPT("hello, how are you? Can you tell me what's a Fibonacci Number?");
                txt.setText(response);
```

This is all I see in the Android Studio Console:

> 2023-09-16 16:13:09: Launching app on
> 'Pixel_3a_API_34_extension_level_7_x86_64. $ adb shell am start -n
> "com.example.gptapi_connect/com.example.gptapi_connect.MainActivity"
> -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -D --suspend --splashscreen-show-icon
>
> Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN
> cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER]
> cmp=com.example.gptapi_connect/.MainActivity }
>
> Connected to the target VM, address: 'localhost:37483', transport:
> 'socket' Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:37483',
> transport: 'socket'

Comment: What happens when you don't try to catch exceptions when doing the HTTP call? My guess is [How can I fix 'android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException'?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6343166/295004) Also read: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr and https://developer.android.com/guide/background/asynchronous

Comment: Yeah.. The problem is when in Android you use the main thread to make network conncetion. Thanks

Comment: If your question is answered, you may just want to delete the question as it would be a dup of the link. Also your API key is in the post.

Comment: @AmirJalilifard You'd better get a new API key and deactivate the old one since anyone can see the edit history, which means your API key as well.

Comment: Yeah.. Already did it